# How to correct type errors with mypy library

Tags: python

I check my code using `mypy`. I got these errors:

1. I have an object `names: List[str]`, for `len(names)` I get

   `Argument 1 to "len" has incompatible type "Optional[List[str]]"; expected "Sized"`

   When I try to index like `names[i]` I get:

   `Value of type "Optional[List[str]]" is not indexable`
2. I have an object `matrix: List[List[int]]`, similarly `matrix[i][j]`

   `Value of type "Optional[List[List[int]]]" is not indexable`
3. I have an object

   ```
    def func() -> Dict[str, List[str]]
        g = {"1": ["2"],
        "2": ["3"]}
        return g
   ```

   annotated as `Dict[str, List[str]]`, I get an error:

   `Incompatible return value type (got "Dict[str, object]", expected "Dict[str, List[str]]")`

   I don't understand, why I got this type. If I change it to `Dict[str, object]`, I get another errors in my code like in 4.
4. When I try to use my object:

   ```
    d: DefaultDict[str, List[str]] = defaultdict(list)
    for obj in g:
        d[obj].extend(g.get(obj))
   ```

   I get this error:

   `Argument 1 to "extend" of "list" has incompatible type "Optional[List[str]]"; expected "Iterable[str]"`

I am new in `python` and don't understand principles of working with `mypy`- how should I annotate types so as not to get similar errors?

Comment: You need to provide [mcve]

Comment: 1. & 2. Apparently you have wrapped these types in `Optional` which means it can be `None` which is neither sized nor indexable. 3. I can't reproduce this one. 4. `d.get` returns `None` if the key is not present. `None` is not iterable and hence cannot be used with `extend`. You need to use `d[obj]` instead. Or even better `for k, v in g.items(): d[k].extend(v)`. Anyway, please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that allows to reproduce all the mentioned errors.

Answer (score 2):

In number 4.
when you use `.get()` method the return type becomes optional i.e. if you were expecting to get `List[str]` it would be `Optional[list[str]]` this is equivalent to
`[None, List[str]]`. To overcome this you could do following:-

```
if g.get(obj) is None:
     raise RunTimeError("Not found")
```